# How to loop if invalid input in prompt

Tags: javascript

For the final input, your program prompts the user for their year of study. Once again, this is not a
required field, that is, a default value of 1 (as in 1st year of study) should be submitted if the user chooses
to leave this field blank. Additionally, you must validate the data the user provides (if provided) to ensure
that it is not less than 1, and not greater than 3 (valid range is 1-3 years of study).

If your solution detects invalid input, your program must loop to allow the user to re-enter year of study,
this process continues indefinitely, until valid input is detected.

---

I have tried a few different methods and this is my most recent attempt, but after 5 hours, I needed to ask for help. Code is below ( Yes, I'm a noob :( )

```
do {
   var yearofStudy = prompt("Please enter your Year of Study", "1")
    console.log(yearofStudy)
    }
while
    ( yearofStudy > 1 && yearofStudy <4 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition is probably the inverse of what you mean. You probably want to keep prompting while the value is *outside* of the range.

```js
do {
   var yearofStudy = parseInt(prompt("Please enter your Year of Study", "1"));
   console.log(yearofStudy)
} while ( yearofStudy < 1 || yearofStudy > 3 )
```

Comment: @str1ng The poster of this answer isn't who responded to you, I'm the one who pointed out that you were (and still seem to be) unnecessarily antagonistic. Please try to be constructive without the personal jabs in future, we're here to help people and everyone makes mistakes, 60k rep or 400.

Comment: @DBS I do agree about part that everyone makes mistakes + that I need to be more specific what was the problem (kinda didn't feel need to re-write everything again since it's included in my answer and if you read it out, it will get in everyone's brain that this one is wrong), but my point here mainly was not about making just logical mistakes, but rather reading question and not flying-over it, and assuming that you got it right.

Comment: I sort of skimmed the narrative part of the OP (my mistake), and made (possibly cultural) error of assuming 1-4 years as it is in many US high school, colleges and universities.  I must've missed a deleted remark from @str1ng, but I guess it was less than charitable. Anyway, like other parts of the online world, SO often makes people seem more antagonistic than they really are.  I've edited my answer to correct my error.

Comment: The top number should be 3, this allows 4, it’s still exactly what the op needs with that minor change.

Comment: Thanks @James. Fixed it. In a second epic bungle of the night, I edited the other poster's answer to fix mine (the person apparently angrily critiquing this one), making theirs wrong *and* leaving mine wrong. I think I've  repaired everything.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specified that you have to use do-while, then using while this way is totally okay and easier to understand.

You have some logical bugs, because your if statement, then (suppose that your code does work), you are checking if user input is bigger then 1, where if you input 1 it's equal to it -> but you're requested to accept that as a yearofStudy, also you need to check if user input is greater then 3, if yes, then ask for input again, you don't want to check if input is greater then 4 as you don't want accept grades 5,6,7,8,9....

```
var statement = true;
    while (statement){
    var yearofStudy = prompt("Please enter your Year of Study", "1");
    if(yearofStudy > 0 && yearofStudy < 4){
    break;
    }
 }
```